# Python - nested dictionary remove key and update dictionary name

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary which contains a list and would like to do the following:

1. Update the dictionary name to `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` instead of `dict1`, `dict2`
2. Remove `key3` and it's values from the dictionary

Here is the current input example:

```
{'dict_1': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']} 'dict_2': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}}
```

Desired output:

```
{'A': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3']} 'B': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3']}}
```

I have tried using ascii lowercase to change letter but this did not work.
To remove key3 I tried using del and pop which did not work either.
Please could someone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where is C and D?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on the question, And also provide the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution involving `ascii values` and `.pop()`.

Try this :

```
nested_dict = {
    'dict_1': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']},
    'dict_2': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3'], 'key3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}}

key_name = 'A'

new_nested_dict = {}

for k, v in nested_dict.items():
    v.pop('key3', None)
    new_nested_dict[key_name] = v
    key_name = chr(ord(key_name) + 1)

print(new_nested_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3']}, 'B': {'key1': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'], 'key2': ['1', '2', '3']}}
```